# cannot run the angularjs file controller error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

angular controller cannot be connected with index.html the project is run with http-server with node.js installed.

classifieds.js

```
      `(function() {
             "use strict";
            angular
            .module("ngClassifieds")
             .controller("ClassifiedsCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
           $scope.name ={text: 'Asif'};
            };
                }]();`
```

index.html

```
            `<!DOCTYPE html>
              <html>
             <head>
                <title>ngClassifieds</title>
             </head>
        <body ng-app="ngClassfieds" ng-controller="ClassifiedsCtrl">

       <input type="text" placeholder="Whats your name" ng-model="name" >
       <h1>{{greeting.text}}</h1>
         <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"> </script>
         <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
      <script src="components/classifieds.js"></script>
       </body>
        </html>`
```

Comment: to make a 'ngClassifieds' module use,  angular.module("ngClassifieds", [])..

Answer (score 0):

Your classified.js file should look like this

```
angular.module("ngClassifieds",[])
     //you should pass an empty array in every module NOTE:inside the array it can the injected field

    (function() {
                 "use strict";

                 .controller("ClassifiedsCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
               $scope.name ={text: 'Asif'};
                };
                    }]();
```